# onPaste event on jquery not update while using mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the onpaste event for detect the paste in input element. It works fine when we paste using **ctrl + v** but I use mouse to paste **rightclick + paste** it wont update the value. What I do wrong in here. Can anyone assist me.

```
$("input").on("keyup paste",function(){
      $("#result").text($(this).val());
});
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AbntQ/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried the paste event? not keyup paste

Comment: keyup is for while typing in the input element. I bind the multiple event keyup and paste thats all.

Comment: @AndreasLindgren, if you have nothing to say, then don't say anything - `jQuery on(...)` accepts multiple events separated by space.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that @ElmoVanKielmo, I didn't know it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just try this:

```
$('input').bind('input propertychange', function() {
    $("#result").text($(this).val());
});
```

And the fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/Frnc7/

Comment: This also adds text to #result if text ist entered normally. Is this intended?

Comment: @StefanSurkamp but this is event i add $('input').bind('keyup paste input propertychange'). so Its working for me now

Comment: @StefanSurkamp, `keyup` event was in the question, so what's the problem?

Comment: Ugh, overlooked that. Sorry, no probleme here ;)

Comment: @StefanSurkamp, then any upvote is wellcome. I gave +1 for your solution as I consider it useful too.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a timeout...

```
$('input').on('paste', function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('#result').text($('input').val());
  }, 100);
});
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AbntQ/2/)

Comment: Thanks Stefan, It works because you update it explicitly. I ask for any event to do this, because I use multiple handler and timer is not fine here.